# Create orphan instances or add spurious dependencies?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm working on updating my [ReadArgs package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ReadArgs-1.1).  I had a request to add `Arguable` instances for Data.Text and [FileSystem.Path.FilePath](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/system-filepath/latest/doc/html/Filesystem-Path.html#t%3aFilePath). The former is no big deal, since it's in the `base` package, but the latter requires `system-filepath`

So I could release a `ReadArgs-ext` package, chock full of orphan instances, or I could update the `ReadArgs` package with an additional external dependency. Which option makes more sense?

Comment: I would definitely say the -exts. You want the instances to be available if people need them, instead of forcing a dependency on them so the instances are actually usable.
Just make sure it's clear from the documentation that there is another package with these instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual rule of thumb is to tend towards adding the instances for packages that are in the Haskell Platform, but don't involve less portable elements such as graphics. This covers both `filepath` and `text`. Since you are already dealing with the outside world for command line arguments, neither one of those seems like a particularly egregious addition.

Orphans can lead to pretty terrible problems.

I don't use them in 95% of my packages, and I go out of my way to avoid packages that use them.

The two exceptions I have at this point are a few missing monoids in `reducers` and a package full of `vector-instances` I picked up because I wasn't willing to make my entire hierarchy of packages depend on `vector`, downgrading everything from `Safe` to `Trustworthy`.

I find when I'm tempted to add an orphan instance, I can usually work around it by providing some kind of `WrappedMonad`-like newtype wrapper for lifting or lowering another class.